# KSQL table get old and new value

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Is it possible in KSQL to stream out the old and new values from a table? We'd like to use a table as a store of values and when one changes stream out a "reversal" value which is the previous one, tagged in some way, and the new value so that we can just handle the delta in downstream systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka tables are generally used for storing the latest values. So for example say stream with key '123' exist in table and a new stream with same key '123' but different column value appears on topic, this will override(upsert) the existing value in table.

So probably its not a great idea to do it on Table.

Your use case is not clear to me still my suggestion would be you need to have some mechanism either in the source of stream or using timestamp to deal with delta feed.

Comment: We could add a custom processor on a topic to do this, I just thought it would be a nice fit for KSQL

Comment: Correct, you can also try custom Kafka connector to pull data from various sources or you can write your own connector to pull delta feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. Does require some juggling.

Create table to keep last state

```
create table v1_mux_connection_ping_ta
as 
select 
  assetid, 
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET(pingable) pingable
from v1_mux_connection_ping_st_parse 
group by assetid;
```

Problem is it also emits no-changes. A solution is to translate the table to a stream.

```
CREATE STREAM v1_mux_connection_ping_ta_s 
  (assetId VARCHAR KEY, pingable VARCHAR) 
WITH (kafka_topic='V1_MUX_CONNECTION_PING_TA', value_format='JSON');
```

To arrive at only changed values

```
create table d_opt_details as 
select 
  s.assetId,
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET(s.pingable) new,
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET(s.pingable, 2)[1] old
from v1_mux_connection_ping_ta_s s
group by
  s.assetId;

create table opt_details as 
select 
  s.assetId, s.new as pingable
from d_opt_details s
where new != old;
```